# Unable to read redis request from stream

Tags: rust, redis

I have following code to read from a network request:

```
fn handle_connection(mut stream: TcpStream) {
    let buf_reader = BufReader::new(&mut stream);
    let req: Vec<_> = buf_reader
        .lines()
        .map(|result| result.unwrap())
        .take_while(|line| !line.is_empty())
        .collect();

    println!("Request: {:#?}", req);
}
```

This works as expected for http request.

But for a redis request, like 'redis-cli PING', it is not able to read and timeouts.

What mistake am I making?

Comment: HTTP and Redis' protocol are not comparable. Redis doesn't use an empty newline to end a request AFAIK. Have you read the spec? https://redis.io/docs/reference/protocol-spec